# Draw different confidence intervals in forest plot

Tags: r, plot

I try to create different confidence intervals with boxes in forest plot.
I want to plot `c(fpDrawNormalCI, fpDrawCircleCI)` depending on line p-value. My `DF`

```
l  hr u p-value names
1  2  3  0.01    A
2  3  4  0.0001  B
3  4  5  0.01    C
```

If the p-value is less than 0.001 the box should be `fpDrawNormalCI`, otherwise `fpDrawCircleCI`

I create forestplot by using the following code

```
library(forestplot)
forestplot(DF$names,DF$hr, DF$l, DF$u, fn.ci_norm=c(fpDrawNormalCI))
```

I have tried to use `if () else () ifelse ()` but it didnt work.
Could you please help me. Thank you beforehand.

Comment: can't reproduce you plot. please prvoide a good working example

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is either use the `size` argument or the confidence interval width and then pass onto subfunctions. If you have a that a confidence interval width of *20 == p-value 0.001* then you could do:

```
custom_ci_norm = function(lower_limit,
                           estimate,
                           upper_limit,
                           ...) {
  if((upper_limit - lower_limit) > 20){
     return fpDrawCircleCI(lower_limit,
                           estimate,
                           upper_limit,
                           ...)
  }else{
     return fpDrawNormalCI(lower_limit,
                           estimate,
                           upper_limit,
                           ...)
  }
}
```